# SDN 2.1.0/neo4j 1.8: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot obtain single field value for field 'schoolRef'

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I am able add and save multiple SchoolRef, but am getting the error after retrieving the (ancestor and eagerly fetching the) Education object and then attempting to add another SchoolRef.  This was working with SDN 2.0.1, but I've also changed other things, including the Repository/Cypher query below, so I can't isolate it to the upgrade.

```
@Fetch @RelatedTo(type = "EDUCATION_HAS_SCHOOLREF")
private Set<SchoolRef> schoolRefs = new HashSet<SchoolRef>();

public Education() {
}

public void addSchoolRef(SchoolRef schoolRef) {
    getSchoolRefs().add(schoolRef);
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User>, CypherDslRepository<User> {

@Query("start id=node:Identifier(identifier={0}) match id<-[:USER_HAS_IDENTIFIER]-user return user")
public User findById(String id);
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot obtain single field value for field 'schoolRef'
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToSingleFieldAccessor.getValue(RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.createEntityFromState(Neo4jTemplate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.createEntitySetFromRelationshipEndNodes(RelationshipHelper.java:130)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToFieldAccessor.createEntitySetFromRelationshipEndNodes(RelatedToFieldAccessor.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToSingleFieldAccessor.getValue(RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:244)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.getOrCreateState(RelationshipHelper.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.createSetOfTargetNodes(RelationshipHelper.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToFieldAccessor.createSetOfTargetNodes(RelatedToFieldAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessor.setValue(RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.updateValue(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.update(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.add(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:108)
```

---- Edit: 
Same error, but under different circumstances..

```
    School school = new School();
    school = neo4j.repositoryFor(School.class).save(school);

    User user1 = new User("Junit", "1");
    SchoolRef schoolRef1 = new SchoolRef();
    schoolRef1.setSchool(school);
    user1.addSchoolRef(schoolRef1);
    user1 = neo4j.repositoryFor(User.class).save(user1);

    User user2 = new User("Junit", "2");
    SchoolRef schoolRef2 = new SchoolRef();
    schoolRef2.setSchool(school);
    user2.addSchoolRef(schoolRef2);
    user2 = neo4j.repositoryFor(User.class).save(user2);  // <- error here
```

Comment: How do you get the Education entity? Via Neo4jTemplate, a repository, a cypher query, ...?

Comment: There seems to be a member called `schoolRef` in your class, and you are looking wrongly at `schoolRefs`?

Comment: @tstorms I updated with the question with the repository and cypher query.

Comment: @PeterNeubauer I created a new SchoolRef object and then get the above error when adding it to the Set of persisted SchoolRefs.

Comment: It happens when saving a link to a node which was already persisted in conjunction with the Fetch annotation. Workaround is to remove @Fetch.

Comment: Workaround is no good.  The save is successful, but its the (lazy) fetch that fails now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes I can be blind to the obvious problem...

In my case, SchoolRef references a single school, but schools can have many schoolRefs.  I had incorrectly implemented School with a single reference back to SchoolRef.

I was able to create multiple SchoolRefs which referenced a single School, but got this error when I tried to fetch a School which had the multiple references.

Answer (score -1):

We ran into this issue as well, but it was due to having a separate relationship with the same label.